# How do I check how LONG the sending transaction lasts for?

Tags: transactions

I created a new eos acc, I sent some eos from my crypto exchange account.It worked.

I have a transaction id, I found it in block explorer. But it does not give much info about HOW LONG or when the transaction started and ENDED.

[image]

[the tx link here](https://eosflare.io/tx/0BD456B6D0A168006003A4A8865FD4D6045A0510595387881ADA92C4AE2D40DA)

Answer (score 1):

### In General

The mainnet of EOS.IO has a **block time of 0.5 sec** because of the DPoS, where a bundle of transactions is processed turnwise.

Transactions can at the moment take **up to 150ms**, otherwise they will be cancelled.

I don't know, if it is possible to view the exact time when a BP has received your actions/transactions but you can look at the timestamp of the block, subtract 0.5 sec and look at the CPU time you have used. Also some bias is possible, which means some unpredictable small delay (maybe through network or CPU schedule). Here are some approximations:

---

#### Possible start time [s_1, s_2]:

> s_1 = timestamp of block - block time
>
> s_2 = timestamp of block - CPU time

#### Possible end time [e_1, e_2]:

> e_1 = s_2
>
> e_2 = timestamp of block

#### In your case:

> s_1 = Apr 29, 2019, 10:50:57.000 PM - 0.5 sec = Apr 29, 2019,
> **10:50:07.000** PM
>
> s_2 = Apr 29, 2019, 10:50:57.000 PM - 6,126 µs (0.000006126sec)
>
> e_1 = Apr 29, 2019, 10:50:57.000 PM - 6,126 µs (0.000006126sec)
>
> e_2 = Apr 29, 2019, 10:50:57.000 PM

So this gives you an approximation between the 0.5 sec when your transaction has been executed.

**This concept is fundamentally different from (PoW) Blockchains that do not limit the transaction execution time like Ethereum.**

#### Recommendation:

I personally like [this block explorer](https://eostracker.io/transactions/55570949/0bd456b6d0a168006003a4a8865fd4d6045a0510595387881ada92c4ae2d40da).